# How to enable external access to Apache web server?

Tags: android, windows, apache

I have some files on Apache web server. I use mobile's WiFi hot spot to connect PC to internet. By specifying the IPv4 address of the PC, I'm able to load the files both on PC and mobile(WiFi hot spot provider only) browsers.

But, I'm unable to load these files on other devices. I followed [this](http://www.codepuppet.com/2014/02/08/enabling-external-access-to-your-apache-web-server-on-windows-7/) tutorial to enable external access. When I give the default gateway, I'm getting the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Where am I going wrong? How to do port forwarding for mobile wifi hotspots?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the mobile device. You will need to use a router and open port 80 for the computer that's running apache. I don't think it could be done using a mobile carrier but even if it could it would probably be very very slow.